# What does "wrapping" mean in programming?

Tags: terminology, definition, word-wrap

In programming literature and on internet in general I noticed frequent use of term *"wrapping"*.

For example "to wrap library in classes" or to "wrap database". Is that official in programming or just a slang? And what is the best way to describe it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Wrap" is a standard English word meaning "Cover or enclose". Typically programmers use it to mean enclosing the functionality of something with something else. It's a fairly widely accepted term. There is no "official programming terms" guideline, so that's about as close as it gets.

#### Example:

- a wrapper function is a function that calls another function;
- a wrapping class is a class that holds inside itself a reference to another object;
- the *Facade* design-pattern is a class/object that wraps around another object, for the purpose of simplifying the interface to access/use such object;
- a *Decorator* design-pattern is a class/object that wraps around another object at run-time, for the purpose of enhancing the object's interface with new functionality (without having to modify the object itself).

Comment: Hi  Amber - would you be able to elaborate on the following re: wrappers - that they: "enclose the functionality of something with something else."?

Comment: Quite late to the party but I added some examples to the answer. I hope they make the *"wrapper"* concept more clear for other users.